# What is the proper way to get the data for Highcharts in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

My Rails website display a simple table about name and age of students.

```
name  age
Lily  25
Tom   27
Chris 19
...
```

So I have `@names = Student.pluck(:name)`, `@ages = Student.pluck(:age)`. Now I would like to generate a line chart by using Highcharts:

**HTML:** `<div id='students-chart'></div>`

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {
  Highcharts.chart('students_chart', {
    ...
  };
};
```

Now I should provide the name and age to the chart as the xAxis and yAxis. The simplest way is to include the JavaScript in the `html.erb` file and provide the data by `<%= @names %>` and `<%= @ages %>`. However, it's not recommended, and I want to put the JavaScript code in the `assets/javascripts/students.js` file.

A very common way to fetch the data in the JavaScript file is using the Ajax, however, my data is already in the page so I don't want to add an extra action in the controller to send the data.

**So what's the best practice to get the data for the Highcharts?** `data-` attribute?

No front-end frameworks in the project, only `jQuery`. I know some gems could help me like `Chartkick` or `LazyHighCharts`, but I would like to know the basic strategy.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to show the chart, just jQuery getting data from the controller.

In controller fetch the data, adjust and convert to `json`. Customise respect to on your models. Here is an example with an array of hashes (data are passed as arrays):

```
@series = [ {name: 'Lily', data: [25]}, {name: 'Tom', data: [27]}, {name: 'Chris', data: [19]} ].to_json
```

For example, if your `User` model includes the age column, you can adjust like this:

```
@series = User.all.map{ |user| {name: user.name, data: [user.age]} }.to_json
```

In view (customise as you will), passing the variable here:

```
<div id='students_chart'></div>
<script>
  $(function () { 
    var myChart = Highcharts.chart('students_chart', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'User ages'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Users']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Age'
            }
        },
        series: <%= raw @series %>
    });
});
</script>
```

---

**Edit - get data from server**

Instead of sending data to view, render as json (no need to add e new action):

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @series }
end
```

Then place the javascript in a file and get json data using [`jQuery.getJSON()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/):

```
$.getJSON(window.location.href, function(json) {
  var highChartData = json;
  console.log(json)
  var myChart = Highcharts.chart('students_chart', {
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'User ages'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Users']
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
      text: 'Age'
      }
    },
    series: highChartData
  });    
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I mentioned, I have been told that it's dirty if we mixed the js and html in the view template. So I am looking for another way to implement it.

Comment: Oops, I missed that part. I made an edit to get data from server by url.